# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable ARRAY

Tags: python, arrays, function, unique

Im trying to create a function called "exists " that checks if a given number from user already exists in the array.I keep getting the errror "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable"

I have no idea how to continue on solving it.Here's my code:

```
from numpy import*
t=array([int]*10)
#Takes the length of array from user,should be between 5 AND 10
def taille():
    n = int(input("Donner le taille de tableau: "))
    while n<5 or n >10:
        n = int(input("Donner une taille 5<=n<=10: "))
    return(n)

#CHECKS IF GIVEN NUMBER EXISTS IN ARRAY
def exist(t,n):
    Found = False
    for i in range(n):
        if t[i] in t[i+1:]:
            Found = True
    return(Found)




#Fills the array from user input
def remplir(t,n):
    t[0]=int(input("donner t[0]: "))

    for i in range(1,n):
        t[i] = int(input("Donner une element: "))
        while exist(t[i]) == True:
            t[i] = int(input("Donner un element distinct!: "))

#Sorts array
def shell(t,n):
    p =0
    while p<n:
        p = p*3+1
    while p!=1:
        for i in range(t):
            key = t[i]
            j = i-1
            while j>=0 and t[j]>key:
                t[j+1] = t[j]
                j-=1
            t[j+1] = key
#Prints it
def affichage(t,n):
    for i in range(n):
        print(t[i])

n = taille()
remplir(t,n)
shell(t,n)
affichage(t,n)
```

Comment: `t=array([int]*10)` should be `t=array([int()]*10)` or `t=array([0]*10)`. You're putting the `int` function itself into the array, not making an array of integers.

Comment: You can also just use `t = zeros(10)`

Comment: You'e also calling the `exist` function with input `t[i]`, and then trying to do `t[i]` again inside the `exist` function...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do your own debugging first. You need to provide a [mre].